# How to capture logs from databricks notebook and store them to data lake gen2

Tags: scala, logging, log4j, databricks, azure-databricks

How to capture logs from Databricks Notebook code and store it into a file that is in Azure data lake gen 2?

I want to implement custom logs for my code which is in the Scala language.

Comment: What does this have to do with Scala? What you just asked here is not a question. Its a request for writing a book.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python azure-storage-logging library.

> azure-storage-logging provides functionality to send output from the
> standard Python logging APIs to Microsoft Azure Storage.

```
import logging
from azure_storage_logging.handlers import TableStorageHandler

# configure the handler and add it to the logger
logger = logging.getLogger('example')
handler = TableStorageHandler(account_name='mystorageaccountname',
                              account_key='mystorageaccountkey',
                              extra_properties=('%(hostname)s',
                                                '%(levelname)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

# output log messages
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warning message')
logger.error('error message')
```

Refer: https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-logging/